# How to interpret a "Thank you for all your hard work" statement before actual completion of work?

Tags: communication, colleagues, performance-reviews, performance, supervision

When your supervisor or team lead says, **thank you for all your hard work** towards the end of the project , but the project has not concluded and some work still pending, are they being sarcastic or genuine how do I interpret this ? Thanks. From my perspective things are still a bit chaotic and some effort is still necessary to bring this project to a smooth conclusion.

Comment: The project doesn't have to be fully complete for a manager to be thankful for the effort you've put in so far. Good managers are appreciative of the people on their team.

Comment: If you are questioning this, are you really questioning yourself about your level of effort? Are you thinking you could, or should, have done better?

Comment: @AhirBhairavOrai How did you know Seth was not going to write another comment? Why did you say thanks after the first comment? Think about it, and compare with your scenario, and you're welcome. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> When your supervisor or team lead says, thank you for all your
> hardwork towards the end of the project , but the project has not
> concluded and some work still pending, are they being sarcastic or
> genuine how do I interpret this ?

Assume positive intent.

Only you know your supervisor/team lead, and only you heard how it was actually said, so you are clearly in the best position to interpret what they mean.

But absent any indications to the contrary, just take it for what it is - a nice little "thank you" and an indication that they are noticing the work you are doing.

Comment: It is absolutely normal to thank people for their hard work when they have done hard work, even if the work is not finished.

Answer (score 3):

It really does not matter what they are *meaning*, take it on the face value.

- Mostly, it's only common (and expected) that as a lead, you should be able to recognize, appreciate and reward the achievements of your team on a regular basis. A simple thank you is a very welcome gesture to express the gratitude, irrespective of the project status. Sometimes, positive and encouraging words really do miracles. As the saying goes

> *Motivation is like bathing, it's needed and recommended regularly.*

- On a slimmer chance, if your team lead has resorted to sarcasm to convey the feedback about poor performance, then there there is some serious malfunction that has crept into the team dynamics that needs to be addressed first. This is a professional work environment, not a casual college gathering / friends' reunion. Also your team lead is overdue for an effective communication training. This is very unlikely (although not impossible) that this was sarcasm, unless there is a follow-up which strongly points towards that.

**TL;DR** Assume good intent, don't assume malice.

Comment: Your TL;DR is just good general advice for life. Most people just don't have the time or energy for real malice. See also: [Hanlon's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor)

Answer (score 1):

Saying, "Thank you," makes people feel appreciated, even mid-project. Towards the end of a project, people start updating their resumes because no one wants to be the last one on a project. Management needs to make sure that people feel appreciated so that they can actually get to end of the project. People who feel appreciated do more for you than people that don't feel appreciated.